# How to add mean value of groupby function based on dataframe A to another dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my notebook I have 3 dataframes.

I would like to calculate the mean age based on Pclass and Age. I achieved this by using a groupby function. The result of the groupby function will override the NaN fields:

```
avg = traindf_cln.groupby(["Pclass", "Sex"])["Age"].transform('mean')
traindf_cln["Age"].fillna(avg, inplace=True)
validationdf_cln["Age"].fillna(avg, inplace=True)
testdf_cln["Age"].fillna(avg, inplace=True)
```

The problem is that the code above is only working on the traindf_cln dataframe and not on the other two.

I think the issue is that you can't use a value (of a groupby) of a specific dataframe on another dataframe.

How can I fix this?

Dataframe traindf_cln:
[image]

Edit:

New code:

```
group = traindf_cln.groupby(["Pclass", "Sex"])["Age"].mean()

lookup_keys = pd.Series(tuple(zip(traindf_cln["Pclass"], traindf_cln["Sex"])))
traindf_cln["Age"].fillna(lookup_keys.map(group), inplace=True)

lookup_keys_val = pd.Series(tuple(zip(validationdf_cln["Pclass"], validationdf_cln["Sex"])))
validationdf_cln["Age"].fillna(lookup_keys_val.map(group), inplace=True)
```

Few samples of traindf_cln where Age is still NaN. Some did change, but not all of them.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing the DFs

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use transform, just a groupby object that can then be mapped onto the `Pclass` and `Sex` columns of the test/validation DataFrames. Here we create a Series with tuples of `Pclass` and `Sex` that can be used to map the groupby values into the missing `Age` data:

```
group = traindf_cln.groupby(["Pclass", "Sex"])["Age"].mean()
lookup_keys = pd.Series(tuple(zip(traindf_cln["Pclass"], traindf_cln["Sex"])))
traindf_cln["Age"].fillna(lookup_keys.map(group), inplace=True)
```

Then just repeat the final 2 lines using the same group object on the test/validation sets.

Comment: Before splitting isn't an option because I also need to do this with other datasets. This is a Keggle project and I also need to do this transform on the Kaggle test set.

Comment: I can't do transformations on a test dataframe based on the test dataframe because my (ml) model will not be correct anymore.

Comment: I see what you mean. So you would need to encode the information from the training set into a function/mapping which can be applied to the `Pclass` and `Sex` columns in the validation/test sets. I will update my anwser.

Comment: It's not working (even not working on the traindf_cln dataset) :(

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `traindf_cln` dataset?

Comment: What error message are you getting with my solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221280/discussion-between-ceelearn-anddo-and-toby-petty).